# How do I earn the "An Extraordinary Man" achievement?

Tags: achievements, assassins-creed-3

The "An Extraordinary Man" achievement requires you complete the Homestead challenge "Encyclopedia of the Common Man." I can't figure out how to do it though. The instructions that briefly came up told me something about using left-trigger but I don't know what to do beyond that. I just sit there targeting one of my citizens and starring at them like some sort of weirdo. How do I correctly do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is kind of weird - basically, you need to target them with the trigger *in the middle of doing the proper tasks*.  So for example, catch the farmers while they're milking cows, the tailor knitting, etc.  It's the sort of things you'd expect to find in the "Encyclopedia of the Common Man".  Generally you'll probably have to leave the area and come back a lot to easily see everything. (I don't have a full list of activities handy but I can maybe try to collate one later when I'm back in front of the game.)

Comment: If you look in the logbook, you can see which artisans you need.  (I think it's pretty much everybody, though).

Answer (score 1):

You have to hit <kbd>LB</kbd> for Xbox or <kbd>L1</kbd> for PS3. The best way to ensure you get it is to go eagle vision, see the yellow person while doing task (blue will read clue analyzed and something about it's not scannable) and then hit <kbd>LB</kbd>, you'll snap out of eagle vision and see that a message pops up

Comment: `L1` is the correct button for PS3.